# Git: files are created with incorrect ownership

Tags: git

My site runs with suphp, and requires the owner:group be the same thing. For example jon:jon. The problem is that when git is creating files, it gives them root:root ownership, which makes them unreadable to my site. Is there a way I can set this up so that files are created with the correct ownership?

Answer (score 0):

Git doesn't record file ownership (the loginnames wouldn't make sense from site to site, where a user declared on one site doesn't exist on another)

All you need to do is to initialize your git repo with the right `owner:group`, and with the right umask, set by the `--shared` option of `git init`. For instance:

```
git init --shared=all
```

> Specify that the git repository is to be shared amongst several users.
>   This allows users belonging to the same group to push into that repository.
>   When specified, the config variable "`core.sharedRepository`" is set so that files and directories under $GIT_DIR are created with the requested permissions.